# Ubuntu running XAMPP 100% CPU utilization

Tags: ubuntu, php, xampp

I'm implementing a WordPress intranet site, but it responses very slow, even with a few online visitors I get 100% CPU usage all the time, my setup is the following:

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
XAMPP 7.4.4-0
WordPress 5.5.1

Here is the result of the "top" command after disable all plugins.
Any suggestions?

I have uploaded the /opt/lampp/logs folder, you can see them here: [logs.zip](https://www.mediafire.com/file/snvgb7j0sc52ldj/logs.zip)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hviFV.png)

Comment: Try examining the XAMPP log files, they will point you in the right direction to find the source of this resource utlization. They should be located in `/opt/lampp/logs/`.

Comment: @YevhenStasiv I have uploaded the logs, and there are a lot of connections but I don't know how to interpret them, thanks a lot

Comment: Try disabling the Elementor plugin in WP